# AES python encryption and Fernet Encryption problem

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

I run into trouble when making a text encryption program in python

I use both AES then I also use FERNET

my code is:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
token = f.encrypt(b"this is my text")
print(token)
```

the problem is that
I want the text "this is my text"
is came from the use
but I wasn't able to solve this because of the letter **b** need

any fix with this same in AES there is a b I can't solve how to make it from user input

Comment: `f.encrypt(input().encode())`

Comment: the result is like this
b'random text here'

Comment: is there any way to remove the letter **b** ?

Comment: What? Why? You just asked how to _add_ it. But yes - please google "python convert bytes to string".

Comment: ok thanks done :) thanks for help I quitely new with this